# How stop `click` bubbling through an input element in an accordion header to avoid activation accordion element

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, accordion

I got a jQuery accordion with an `<input>` in the accordion header.
The accordion is "collapsible", but I don´t want the item to expand (or collapse) when clicking inside the `<input>`.

How can I stop the `click` event bubbling through the `<input>` element to avoid activating the accordion element?

Is there some smart way to apply `event.stopPropagation();` (or something similar) to the accordions `beforeActivate`-callback?
Or can this be done directly on the `<input>`s data binding?

From my bindingHandler:

```
       $(element).accordion({
            header: ".accordion-header",
            collapsible: true,
            navigation: true,
            heightStyle: "content",
            active: false,

            beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
                active = $(this).accordion("option", "active");
            },
            activate: function (event, ui) {
                event.stopPropagation(); // This obviously has no effect
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

you're doing it right `.stopPropagation()` is correct, you just don't have it in the right spot, it would go in the click handler of the input.

ex.

```
$(document).on('click', '.my-input', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();   // throw this in for good measures too
     e.stopPropigation();

    //  your code to handle click here
});
```

HTML

```
<input data-bind="click: clickHandler" />
```

Knockout:

```
clickHandler = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();   // throw this in for good measures too
        e.stopPropigation();
};
```

Comment: I´m using knockoutJS and the click-binding. So where should I put it with my <input data-bind="event:{keyup: someFunction}"/>    Inside `someFunction` (that I already is using) or in an additional `event: {click: someOtherFunction}` ?

Comment: edited answer for you,  just remember , to not put () after the function in the HTML.  This will force it to execute when the html is rendered

Comment: Thanks, Scott, but somehow the accordion is still expanding/collapsing when the input has focus. `clickHandler` is invoked (tested with alert();) but  the e.stopPropagation and e.preventDefault seems to have no effect on the accordion behaviour.

Comment: Could this be caused by the `<input>` not being visible at rendering time?
(I have a `<span data-bind=text: mytext, doubleClick: setInputVisibleAndHideThis>` that makes it show).

Comment: Found it!
 $('#myAccordionId').accordion({
            beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
                event.preventDefault();}
        });
Putting this in the click handler prevents the accordion to activate its contents. Has to reactivate after finished editing the `<input>` with 

$('#myAccordionId').accordion({
            beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
                active = $('#accordion').accordion("option", "active");
            }
        });